# How to have different annotations applied to an entity property?

Tags: java, annotations

I have an abstract base entity class with an `id` property.

I would like to have specific annotations applied to this property if the current database is H2:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = id_generator")
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;
```

And some other specific anotations applied to this property if the current database is MySQL:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "native")
@GenericGenerator(name = "native", strategy = "native")
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;
```

The base class:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractEntity {
```

All entity classes extend the base class like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_account")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "id_generator", sequenceName = "sq_id_user")
public class User extends AbstractEntity {
```

Maybe I could leverage some conditional custom annotations ?

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Conditional(DbH2Condition.class)
public @interface DbH2 {
}

public class DbH2Condition implements Condition {

  private static final String DB = "h2";

  @Override
  public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
    return context.getEnvironment().getProperty("db") == null
        || context.getEnvironment().getProperty("db").equals(DB);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add annotations using external byte code manipulation framework, such as JavaAssist, during compile time. But it means that you need to know in compile time of course, which database you will use.